Best repair method for my luggage
I have no clue what the name of this particular area/piece/part of luggage would be called.  I would call it trim, but I have no clue what I am talking about.  I am looking for an ideal DIY repair for the damage done to . Thought that I would look up to see what success other people have had before I go gluing, cementing, sewing and just general frankenstein style and making things worse.  The stitching is exposed and the black piece hanging there is for sure getting caught when the baggage throwers are tossing it around and then it will be ripped even more.


I’m voting to close this question because this is outside the scope of Travel Stackexchange

You can try duct taping the area. Makes your bag easier to recognize on the baggage carousel and less likely to be  stolen since it looks crappy.

@AnishSheela It's borderline but if luggage is outside the scope of travel.SE I wonder what is in scope... May be a slightly better fit for https://diy.stackexchange.com

I agree with @jcaron, it is better to migrate this question to https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Or lifehacks.se?

Yes. Migrating to DIY will get more responses also.

Duct taping a suitcase on the outside seems like sticking an ‘I’m easy to break into’ advert on it. Unless the case was expensive or recently bought, IIWY I’d just replace it.

that piece is called piping. It's taken in the edge seam between 2 side panels to give more structure to the edge, but it's not strictly necessary. This one is broken (torn along the stitch holes) beyond repair. You can safely remove it by simply cutting the torn part. You could bring it to an alteration shop to see if they can replace it if you really wanted. Otherwise, given that it's all plastic, a cyano-acrylate glue applied carefully might just work?

@jcaron NaveedAhmed & AnishSheela, the DIY Stack is for DIY Home Improvement, not anything DIY. This question would be off-topic there. https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
